# Python OpenCV Head Estimation: Trouble detecting faces off-center

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Im trying to follow a code about head estimation on the internet but when I finish coding it, it only works when I was positioned exactly in the center of the camera. When I move my body slightly left or right, it said im looking left or right. Im trying to fix for a day now but I fail everytime.

This is the code:

```
import cv2

model_path = "opencv_face_detector_uint8.pb"
config_path = "opencv_face_detector.pbtxt"
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(model_path, config_path)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

confidence_threshold = 0.5

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300), [104, 117, 123], False, False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()

    for i in range(detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        if confidence > confidence_threshold:
            x1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 3] * frame.shape[1])
            y1 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 4] * frame.shape[0])
            x2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 5] * frame.shape[1])
            y2 = int(detections[0, 0, i, 6] * frame.shape[0])

            face_width = x2 - x1
            face_height = y2 - y1
            face_center_x = x1 + (face_width // 2)

            nose_offset_x = 0.1
            nose_x = face_center_x + int(nose_offset_x * face_width)

            image_width = frame.shape[1]
            yaw_angle = (nose_x - image_width / 2) / (image_width / 2) * 90

            if yaw_angle < -10:
                gaze_direction = "Looking Left"
            elif yaw_angle > 10:
                gaze_direction = "Looking Right"
            else:
                gaze_direction = "Looking Forward"

            cv2.putText(frame, gaze_direction, (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Gaze Direction Estimation", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you please add some debugging info that explains your issue (example input image, debug output image with rectangle of face detection and position of nose detection etc.)? That way it can be easier for others to reproduce what you have and what you would expect.